# postgres, how to put all the content of a table in a hash?

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I would like to put all the results from a select to a hash, that will have the name of the table as the key and the value is an array that will have the rows, here is what I did so far :

```
def table_content_to_hash(table)
 hash = {}
 rs = @pg_conn.exec "SELECT * FROM #{table}";
 rs.each do |child|
  # want to put table name as key and value is an array that has the rows
  hash['#{table}'] = child  # THIS ONE IS WRONG
 end
 puts hash
end
```

Update, my code works after using Spickermann solution, here is the result :

```
{"company"=>[{"id"=>"1", "name"=>"Paul", "age"=>"32", "address"=>"California                                        ", "salary"=>"20000"}, {"id"=>"2", "name"=>"Allen", "age"=>"25", "address"=>"Texas                                             ", "salary"=>"15000"}, {"id"=>"3", "name"=>"Teddy", "age"=>"23", "address"=>"Norway
                                    ", "salary"=>"20000"}, {"id"=>"4", "name"=>"Mark", "age"=>"25", "address"=>"Rich-Mond
", "salary"=>"65000"}, {"id"=>"5", "name"=>"David", "age"=>"27", 
"address"=>"Texas                                             ", 
 "salary"=>"85000"}, {"id"=>"6", "name"=>"Kim", "age"=>"22", 
 "address"=>"South-Hall                                        ", 
 "salary"=>"45000"}, {"id"=>"7", "name"=>"James", "age"=>"24", 
  "address"=>"Houston                                           ", 
"salary"=>"10000"}]}
```

I don't know ho to remove that space the value of the address.
Thanks,

Comment: Try `rs.as_json`

Comment: I really hope `table` is not a user-supplied parameter because you're putting it in your query without any sort of escaping or validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize your hash with the table name and an empty array right away:

```
def table_content_to_hash(table)
  hash = { table => [] }

  rows = @pg_conn.exec "SELECT * FROM #{table}";
  rows.each do |row|
    hash[table] << child
  end

  puts hash
end
```

Comment: Thanks spickermann, it works, now I will change the method to take two string : def table_content_to_hash(table1,table2) , and do the samething as your code for both tables, I will have two hashes, how to compare the two hashes to see if the two tables have the same content ? thanks.

Comment: To compare two hashes just use `==` like this: `{ a: 1, b: 2 } == { b: 2, a: 1 } #=> true` But wouldn't it be faster to compare the table in the database with a SQL?

Comment: the two tables come from two different databases, we want to test data migration from a legacy DB (SQL Server) to Postgress,

Comment: I did : expect(hash[table1] == (hash2[table2])) but it passed, the hash2 has two diff thing : "address"=>"Texas0  and  "name"=>"David0" , please look at my hash result in my update question.

Comment: This question is a different issue and has nothing in common with your original question how to build hashes. I suggest that you start a new question for the compare issue.